# How do I upload files to Google Cloud Storage in Objective-C/iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-storage

I've been looking for documentation on how to upload files to my 'bucket' in Google Cloud Storage from my iOS app, but I can't find anything at all on the subject. No documentations, no tutorials, no example projects. Am I completely blind? I am simply trying to find a way for my app-users to upload a file to a "public bucket", and get a URL in return. All I can find is chunks of HTTP-protocols or JSON etc, and I have no idea how to use that, but there's no reference to it either. It feels like the author of those documentations expects me to know everything already. I've found some OSX-example codes, but they are too without documentation, and I've been trying to read the code they have provided, but with no luck.

What I'm looking for is something like this:
(This code is made up. It's what I want. I noticed Google used the prefix GTL* for their classes)

```
NSData *dataToUpload = ... ; //Or UIImage or some movie-format or whatever
NSURL *destination;

GTLStorageUploader *uploader = [GTLStorageUploader alloc]initWithBucket:@"myBucket" withHashOrKeyOrSomething:@"a1b2c3hashkeyOrWhatever"];
destination = [uploader uploadData:dataToUpload];//inBackground etc..
```

It's actually easier than this when using [Parse.com](http://www.parse.com), but there's simply not enough storage space for my app there, so I need to be able to upload the data files to Google Cloud Storage. How?

Comment: Well, the first page of the documentation does say "It assumes that you are familiar with web programming and you are comfortable creating applications that consume web services through HTTP requests." There may not _be_ a super-friendly ObjC wrapper around the API. There is, however, the [Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/). Have you seen that?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes, that's what I'm referring to as OSX-example codes. If you click "Introduction" there, and read the section on "Uploading", then they are only using a very specific example for how to use it with Google Drive, nothing about Cloud Storage. As they have made a class for `GTLDriveFile` and one for `GTLStorage` I assume those are two completely separate things. I can't find anything else about either of them. No matter what I search for regarding this results in finding the source code for `GTLStorage` etc, and there is no documentation inside the code. (And every example is OSX)

Comment: @Sti Hi there..I am running through same problem and yes there are no sample apps that uses their Storage service APIs..there are some sample apps for drive, calender etc but nothing for storage..did you find out solution for the same..I would really appreciate if you can point me to the link where I can find something useful..Thanks!!

Comment: @ShikhaShah Hi, I'm sorry, I didn't find anything at all, and I decided to move away from Google all together. It turned out to be in a pretty early beta-stage for the iOS-community. Maybe it's better support now, but I never found anything. I moved to Amazons S3 service, which have similar prices and waay better support and ease of use. With Amazon's objective-c framework it works almost as my "sample code" above. Check it out at http://aws.amazon.com. However, if you still want to use Google Storage, please let me know if you find out anything, by writing an answer here? Thanks:)

Comment: @Sti Thanks for quick reply. I cant switch to Amazon as I am also using Google Compute Engine for processing purpose. So my Google cloud storage , Google App engine and Google Compute engine are all connected..I already got it working for Android Platform..Its really disappointing that they don't have any sample app or code for the same in iOS..Sure will write my answer here if I find anything.Thanks Again

Comment: @ShikhaShah So, did you ever find anything? I'm giving it another go.. ;)

Comment: Guys, any luck with solution for this problem, I am breaking my head and could not find anything yet?

Comment: @coder123 I gave it another go a while back, and I did get it to work. I broke my head too though, and I still, to this day, wake up from nightmares of this. I don't know if my solution will help you, but I just posted it as an answer. Hope it helps. I seriously recommend going for something else than Google though. I have forgotten everything I did to make it work, so have an open mind about my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I did eventually get this to work. It wasn't pretty, though.
It's quite a long time ago now, so I can't really remember all the logic etc, but I'll post what made it work, and change the ID-stuff. I hope it helps, and sorry I didn't remember to write this when I found out and it was fresh in mind. I don't have time to get into this at the moment.

An **important** note: I also had to change a lot of permissions on the bucket and on the users/authorized on GoogleCloudStorage to make this work. We tried so many different combinations, but I THINK this was the stuff we did:

- On each bucket: "Allow everyone to upload/delete/edit etc".
- On the auth for the entire CloudStorage: "Allow only entities with certain accessToken to access this CloudStorage.
- Allow only *www.yourAppEngineURL.com* to request such an accessToken.

This felt wrong, and still does. If anyone gets a hold of this accessToken, they can do whatever they want as long as that accessToken is valid. Like.. delete all files. But that was the only way we could make it work. Of course, only authorized users could request this accessToken from OUR appEngine, but still.. meh. I'm no security-guru, and this was just a fun project, so we let it go. Now to the code.

When uploading:

```
GTLServiceStorage *serv = [[GTLServiceStorage alloc] init];

serv.additionalHTTPHeaders = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"123123123", @"x-goog-project-id",
                              @"application/json-rpc", @"Content-Type",
                               @"application/json-rpc", @"Accept", nil];


GTLStorageObjectAccessControl *objAccessControl = [GTLStorageObjectAccessControl new];
objAccessControl.entity = @"project-owners-123456"; //Some value from the control panel on CloudStorage or something. Or Apps.. Or AppEngine, not sure.
//Probably connected to the accessToken my AppEngine requests and sends to users.
objAccessControl.role = @"OWNER";

GTLStorageObjectAccessControl *objAccessControl2 = [GTLStorageObjectAccessControl new];
objAccessControl2.entity = @"allUsers";
objAccessControl2.role = @"READER";
//Don't remember why I need both. Or what they do. Hey ho.
//It looks like.. Everybody can read. Only my authorized accessToken-people can write? probably.

GTLStorageBucket *bucket = [[GTLStorageBucket alloc] init];
bucket.name = @"my_bucket";

NSError *err;
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle myLocalFileURLiThink error:&err];
if(err)
{
    NSLog(@"Some error here");
}

GTLUploadParameters *params = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithFileHandle:fileHandle MIMEType:@"video/mp4 (or something else)"];
GTLStorageObject *storageObject = [[GTLStorageObject alloc] init];
storageObject.acl = @[objAccessControl, objAccessControl2];


NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fileName.mp4"];
// should probably be unique.. The url will be cloud.com/my_bucket/fileName.mp4
//You can generate something unique by putting together the user's userID and the timeStamp for the dateTime right now. 
//This user will never upload two things within this second.
storageObject.name = key;
```

After this point in the code I do some magic I'm not gonna post. I ask for and receive an accessToken to use on GoogleCloudStorage from our own API.
I don't remember where or how I got that token to begin with, but I believe that the backend (AppEngine) had to request it from the CloudStorage-thing, using a pretty standard call.
And, as I said in the beginning, we changed some settings on CloudStorage making our AppEngine the only entity allowed to request this token. Or something.. This token has a lifecycle of like.. 15 minutes or so.. I don't know, it's provided by some Google-default-thing. I might look into it later if any of you need it.

```
NSString *receivedAccessToken = @"abc123"; //Received from CloudStorage via AppEngine.
NSString *accessToken = @"Bearer %@", receivedAccessToken" //(pseudo) Because it needed to say "Bearer " first. Don't know why, or how I found out..

[serv setAdditionalHTTPHeaders:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:accessToken forKey:@"Authorization"]];

//Upload-magic:
GTLQueryStorage *query = [GTLQueryStorage queryForObjectsInsertWithObject:storageObject bucket:bucket.name uploadParameters:params];

GTLServiceTicket *t = [serv executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
    //Handle error first.
    NSLog(@"Success!");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        actualURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", yourFullBucketURL /*( e.g www.googleCloud.com/my_bucket)*/, key /*file.mp4*/];
    });
}];
```

And you can track the progress of the upload after this block, with the ticket-object (like, `t.uploadProgressBlock = ...`).

This code has been edited quite a bit for Stack-purposes now, so I might have screwed up something, so I probably doesn't work exactly like this. But read it, and try to understand how it works. Good luck. If you have the option, stay with Amazon or something else, this was not fun to work with. Worst documentation ever. Also, Amazon's S3 uploads/downloads faster than GoogleCloudStorage. I regret changing from Amazon to Google. Amazon had so much better API too, almost like the one in my question.

Here's the code used by AppEngine to request the AccessToken:

```
private GoogleCredential getGoogleCredential(String scope) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
{
    JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                    .setServiceAccountId(Constants.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(Constants.CLOUD_STORAGE_KEY))
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(scope))
                    .build();
    return credential;
}
```

The parameter "scope" sent in to this method is either `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write`

The method returns a GoogleCredential-object, on which you can call `googleCredential.refreshToken()`. I believe this is the call made to get the token. I'm not sure though.

The Constants (email and key) are stuff you need to set up and get from the auth-page on Google Cloud Storage, I think.

This documentation should cover some of it (it looks more documented now than it did then, I think): https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication

Comment: Thanks @Sti for the quick code overview, I have exactly tried the same thing awhile back, the only thing that's keeping me from completing is access Token, that's the big question how did you get access token. Are you using JWT token and requesting access token from google?